# How to put pictures in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a game in NetBeans and I have to put some pictures and when I start the program they are there, but when I do clean and build pictures are not in the JAR file. Can someone help me? I'm not using JFrame form.

Comment: The simplest way, put your pictures folder inside of `src` folder.

Comment: I've put them in src  but when I do clean and build, they are not in JAR file

Comment: I've also put them out of the src folder and in dist folder but nothing

Comment: You can add the pictures manually. 
For example, pic1 is located at `a.a.a.pic1.png`, you can create `a/a/a/` directory in the jar file and put `pic1.png` inside that directory,

Comment: How to create a directory?

Comment: I've also done this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am using JFrame and I think it's similar to whatever you are using while it's on netbeans

1. you have to put them in src folder
2. right click on the jLabel (if you using JFrame you have to add jLabel )
3. choose properties
4. choose icon
5. choose image within project

and you will find all pictures in src folder
this way when you share the JAR file the pictures will be inside it

but if you chose External image in step 5 you will use just the path of the image ( I think here's your problem )